# Meaning of 'it turns my head around'

Tags: meaning-in-context

It used to make me angry when I thought about how he destroyed my life for getting me pregnant.

It makes me sick and IT TURNS MY HEAD AROUND and I feel like collapsing.

Can someone please tell the exact meaning in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is wrong. The actual sentence should be "It makes me sick and **MY HEAD SPINS** and I feel like collapsing."

The closest meaning I found to "turning" in this context is:

> To revolve in the mind; meditate on; ponder

This is not true in the context being sick and being on the verge of collapsing. It doesn't fit there. Moreover, **head turning around** is actually a **physical process**. You have to move your head for that. Head "spinning" is what you **feel**.

Your head "spins" when you are ill(mentally or physically) and are about to faint or when you receive shocking news.

What I think is that the sentence is a direct translation of the speaker's mother tongue.

Comment: Yeah true. Time posted a piece on Instagram about a Nigerian woman who was kidnapped by Boko Haram fighters. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AntonioConte I'm glad it helped!